# use overload relay with stepper motor

Tags: relay, stepper-motor

I need to use a stepper motor 6A with Delta PLC using a stepper motor driver.

My question is do  i need to use an overload protection relay or is there any alternative for stepper motor ?
stepper motor [stepper](http://steppermotors.bholanath.in/stepper-motors/nema-34-86-mm/180-kg-cm-bipolar-stepper-motor-6-2-amp-motor.html)
driver[driver](http://steppermotors.bholanath.in/8-amp-bipolar-microstepping-drive.html)

Comment: I'd very much assume that functionality would have to be part of the motor driver.

Comment: so not required right? i am new to the fied and dont want to fry stepper motor [link](http://steppermotors.bholanath.in/stepper-motors/nema-34-86-mm/180-kg-cm-bipolar-stepper-motor-6-2-amp-motor.html) with driver [link](http://steppermotors.bholanath.in/8-amp-bipolar-microstepping-drive.html)

Comment: You shouldn't be asking me/us. You should be asking the guy who's selling the driver, obviously.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i have seen people who use stepper motor directly with driver. I am new to the field and was thinking someone with more experience could answer maybe a general answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shall he "overload protection relay" protect?

The coil current of the motor? This should be implemented in the driver already, so it is not necessary.

The current to the driver? Well, if you assume that there might be a fault in the driver like a shortcut, this could certainly be a good idea. But that has nothing to do with the stepper motor.